# Where does OS X store USB mouse plist?

Tags: macos, usb, mouse

I've found that often when you are experiencing trouble with a peripheral, deleting the plist file can often fix the problem.

My USB mouse has been sticking/freezing for a second at a time lately.

I've looked throughout `~/Library/Preferences/`, but saw no filenames that make me confident enough to delete any of them.

**UPDATE**

I was able to delete the `com.apple.driver.AppleHIDMouse.plist` file that was showing in the `Terminal` but not in the `Finder`.

```
Pauls-iMac: soliddev$ ls ~/Library/Preferences/ | grep driver
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse.plist
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDMouse.plist
Pauls-iMac: soliddev$ rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleHIDMouse.plist
Pauls-iMac: soliddev$ ls ~/Library/Preferences/ | grep driver
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse.plist
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist
Pauls-iMac: soliddev$
```

Unfortunately, the mouse sticking/freezing persists.

**UPDATE**

At the end of the day, I've bought a new mouse, the problem seems to be fixed for now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The tracking speed is stored in the  ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist file.

```
defaults read -g | grep mouse
"com.apple.mouse.doubleClickThreshold" = "1.1";
"com.apple.mouse.scaling" = "2.5";
```

The slowest speed shown in System Preferences is 0.0 and the highest is 3.0

You can change the speed by editing the plist directly or with `defaults`, but you have to log out and back in.

```
defaults write -g com.apple.mouse.scaling -float 2.1
```

This AppleScript code would change the speed immediately:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal pane "com.apple.preference.mouse"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    set value of slider 3 of window 1 to 9.0 -- maximum, minimum is 0.0
end tell
quit application "System Preferences"
```

EDIT: 
    defaults find mouse
will search your default domains, keys, and values for the word mouse, without the need to pipe to grep.

Comment: You misunderstand... the speed isn't changing, the mouse stops moving completely for a second or two then returns to normal.

Answer (score -1):

In Terminal.app:

`ls ~/Library/Preferences/ | grep mouse`

or

`ls ~/Library/Preferences/ | grep mouse`

or

`ls ~/Library/Preferences/ | grep driver`

should give you a list of suspects.

Comment: Is it an Apple mouse? 

with `ls ~/Library/Preferences/ | grep mouse` I get:
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse.plist .

If your mouse isn't Apple branded, you could try grepping for the makers name.

Comment: It is not an Apple Mouse, it's a Logitech USB mouse. `ls ~/Library/Preferences/ | grep driver` returned 2 files that seem to be bluetooth related and this file: `com.apple.driver.AppleHIDMouse.plist`. Would you think deleting this file might solve the sticking/freezing mouse problem?

Comment: I decided to go ahead and delete the 'com.apple.driver.AppleHIDMouse.plist' file, but when I navigate to `~/Library/Preferences/` via Finder, that file is not there. I have vision of all hidden files/folders, fyi. To be clear, typing `ls ~/Library/Preferences/ | grep driver` in terminal produced `com.apple.driver.AppleHIDMouse.plist`, but That file does not show via the Finder.

Comment: Those files should be visible in the Finder, they're visible on my system. You can try searching in the Finder while you are in the `~/Library/Preferences` folder. Type in the search bar and look for `mouse` , `mouse`, `logitech` , `Logitech`, `usb` or `USB`. If that doesn't show anything, then I don't know.

Comment: Did the Logitech mouse come with software? Did it install a driver? If so reinstall the software or update it if there is that option.